# Can a (rational coefficient) polynomial have roots with two radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was going through my algebra homework and I realized we've never encountered a polynomial with roots with two orders of radicals, i.e. $(x-(3^{1/2}+3^{1/4})$ or something. Now, obviously, you could just multiply out from the factors, but that gives you some really nasty things. My question is: is this a coincidence? Are there certain conditions under which such roots form? Is there a way to prove that they can't form? Is it possible for "nice" polynomials, i.e. ones with rational coefficients?

Comment: There is a polynomial with rational coefficients which has $3^{1/2}+3^{1/4}$ as a root.

Comment: Forget about "rational" coefficients--you just want _integer_ coefficients (it's basically the same thing).

Comment: I strongly suspect you are referencing the [Rational Zeroes Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalZeroTheorem.html).  In fact, arbitrary polynomials, with rational coefficients, generally _do not_ permit rational roots (much less integer roots)...in fact they often times don't even permit _real_ roots.

Answer (score 1):

$(x-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[4]{3})$ is a factor of the degree $8$ polynomial
$$
x^8-12x^6+48x^4-216x^2+36
$$
The way to see that (other than perhaps just noticing that it is obvious) is:

Say you want $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[4]{3}$, then
$$
\sqrt[4]{3}= x-\sqrt{3}\\
3 = (x-\sqrt{3})^4 = x^4-4\sqrt{3}x^3+18x^2-12\sqrt{3}x+9\\
(4x^3+12x)\sqrt{3} = x^4+18x^2+6\\
48x^2(x^2+3)^2=(x^4+18x^2+6)^2\\
48x^2(x^4+6x^2+9)^2=x^8+36x^6+336x^4+216x^2+36\\
x^8-12x^6+48x^4-216x^2+36 = 0
$$

Comment: What is nice is that the four real roots of the equation are $x=\pm \sqrt{3}\pm \sqrt[4]{3}$

Comment: It may be worth noting that this polynomial factors as $\left(x^4-6 x^2-12 x+6\right) \left(x^4-6 x^2+12 x+6\right)$ with the former factor having $\root4\of3+\sqrt3$ as its zero.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to quadratic polynomials will be in the form of $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, and so will only have square roots.  The answer to cubic polynomials will only have cubic roots.

However, the answers to quartic polynomials can have both square and quartic roots (see Gilbert & Gilbert 6th edition for specific computations).

In general, a polynomial of degree $n$ will have only roots of degrees dividing $n$.  So the phenomenon you described occurs because 2 and 3 are prime, and so they cannot have any roots other than their degree.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing the same as Mark Fischler for $x=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt[4]{a}$ the equation would be $$x^8-4 a x^6+2 a (3 a-1) x^4-4 a^2 (a+3) x^2+(a-1)^2 a^2=0$$ for which the four real solutions are $(\pm\sqrt{a}\pm\sqrt[4]{a})$

Answer (score 0):

Others gave you degree eight polynomials that are not irreducible. Here's how to find a quartic.

Interpreting multiplication by $\alpha=\root4\of3+\sqrt3$ as a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear mapping from $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of3)$ to itself gives the following quartic polynomial that has this as a root.
$$m(x)=x^4-6 x^2-12 x+6.$$
With respect to the basis $\{1,3^{1/4},3^{2/4},3^{3/4}\}$ that linear mapping corresponds to the matrix that is the transpose of
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\3&0&0&1\\3&3&0&0\end{array}\right).
$$
I invite you to check that the column vector $(1,3^{1/4},3^{2/4},3^{3/4})^T$ is an eigenvector of $M$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\alpha$. Therefore $\alpha$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial
$$
\chi_M(x)=\det(xI_4-M)=x^4-6 x^2-12 x+6=m(x).
$$

Observe that $m(x)$ is irreducible over the rationals by Eisenstein's criterion.

---

Another way of arriving at the polynomial $m(x)$ is to observe that
$$
([x-\sqrt3]-\root4\of3)([x-\sqrt3]+\root4\of3)=[x-\sqrt3]^2-\sqrt3=x^2-2\sqrt3x+3-\sqrt3,
$$
so $\alpha$ is a solution of the quadratic
$$
x^2+3=\sqrt3(2x-1).
$$
Squaring this equation gives
$$
x^4+6x^2+9=3(4x^2-4x+1).
$$
Moving all the terms to the left gives the polynomial $m(x)$.

Comment: If you have not studied field extensions at all, then my first solution is probably all Greek to you. The second solution is more accessible.