# Find a polynomial with integer coefficients given a noninteger root

Tags: polynomials

Find a polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $a = \sqrt2 + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root.

How would I approach this problem? I've tried Vieta's and the RRT, but not really sure how to use them here.

Comment: Cube both sides of $a-\sqrt2=\root3\of2$. Then move the terms containing square roots to one side, and the rest to the other. Square both sides. Sorry, I won't give you the answer, because, as it happens, this is an exercise on my course. Due tomorrow! But on a continent different from yours, so no worries :-)

Comment: Alternatively you can try and use the method I described [in this recent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1681086/11619). Your $a$ generates a field extension of degree six, so you need to use a 6x6 matrix.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why are you not writing this magnificient hint as an answer?

Comment: @Arthur: A) I want to test whether the OP can solve it themself using this kind of a hint. B) My students know I spend time here. And, as I said, the timing is kinda bad :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is from SUMAC 2016 (stanford summer math camp entrance exam)

Comment: @AnuragA: I'm not sure how I can help to maintain the integrity of SUMAC qualification. I recommend that you just bring this to the notice of the organizers. They can compare the students mailings to the posted answers and figure out who it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:$(a-\sqrt{2})^3 = 2$ and solve for $\sqrt{2}$ and square it again to get an equation in integer coefficients.